# Where are clang-format and clang-format.py in Mac OS X with Xcode Command Line Tools installed?

Tags: c++, macos, clang, clang-format

I am having a hard time finding clang-format and clang-format.py on my Mac OS 10.8.5 with Xcode 5 and its Command Line Tools. I tried `find / -name "clang-format.py"` without luck. Are they already here somewhere hiding, or how would I get this toolchain?

(I'm surprised it doesn't seem readily available since clang is Apple's compiler---in that Apple uses it.)

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Seems like Apple doesn't ship [clang-format](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) with the Command Line Tools. Right now you have at least three options:

- Using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) (*That's the way to go*)
- Using prebuild packages
- Build it yourself

---

### **Homebrew**

As user [johnhaley81](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560726/johnhaley81) pointed out, `clang-format` is now in [homebrew](http://brew.sh/):

> clang-format is now on brew. `brew install clang-format`

Please consider upvoting his [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28325546/289841) if you find this answer useful.

---

### **Prebuild packages**

Pre-build bundles are available at [llvm.org](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html). For Mac OSX, you need to download the *darwin* package.

---

### **Build instructions:**

Here's an instruction on how to do this:
http://nacho4d-nacho4d.blogspot.de/2013/11/clang-format.html

And here's another one:
http://blog.hardcodes.de/articles/63/building-clang-format-and-friends-on-osx-mountain-lion

Comment: The first flag was required and I think the second flag sped things up by skipping the Debug build: `./llvm/configure --disable-compiler-version-checks --enable-optimized` but other than that, it worked as advertised. Thanks!

Comment: I struggled to get it installed (initially), wrote up a post with some helpful tips (mostly for myself) http://staxmanade.com/2015/01/how-to-install-clang-format-and-formatting-objective-c-files/

Comment: clang-format is now on brew. `brew install clang-format`

Comment: `clang-format-diff.py` the problem is, it doesn't find one in your environment

Comment: Do `brew update` if homebrew can't find it at first.

Comment: Even with fresh `brew update`, brew doesn't seem to install clang-format.py for use with vim. I got it from the LLVM website -> "Clang source code" under `tools/clang-format/clang-format.py` (the `el` version is also there, for emacs).

Comment: brew install clang-format , that didn't wok on macOS 10.12.6 and Xcode 8.3.3

Comment: Homebrew is the way to go, sure, if you want it to take ownership of a directory that shouldn't have a user owner....Bad idea though I know many would say there's no risk or it doesn't matter or they don't care.

Answer (score 54):

You can use brew now to install clang-format.

`brew install clang-format`

Answer (score 5):

#### Specific versions of `clang-format`

As of november/2018, current `clang-format` formula on Homebrew points to version `8.0.0`. Run `clang-format --version` to check yours.

If you need older versions of `clang-format`, consider following these steps:

[Installing clang-format version 5 (5.0.2) with homebrew](https://gist.github.com/ffeu/6ffb75d8e8c7d92c0fbeb4b036599c33#gistcomment-2761559)

[Installing clang-format version 7 (7.0.0) with homebrew](https://gist.github.com/ffeu/0460bb1349fa7e4ab4c459a6192cbb25#gistcomment-2765744)

Comment: Hi @heLomaN , the default `clang-format` on brew installs the latest version from 2018-12-18. (check the [PR](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/35794)).

Answer (score 4):

I know this is not a direct answer to the question but if you are just looking to format your code in Xcode. I just used this plug in.

https://github.com/travisjeffery/ClangFormat-Xcode

Comment: Currently I am not (emacs + vim user), but this is certainly handy to know about.

Comment: If you use this plugin you can find clang-format in the installed plugin at: ~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/ClangFormat.xcplugin/Contents/Resources/clang-format

Answer (score 4):

In my case I installed clang-format with brew install and located here:
**/usr/local/bin/clang-format**

Answer (score 2):

If you have the `llvm` toolchain already installed, you can find the `clang-format.py` file in `/usr/local/opt/llvm/share/clang/clang-format.py` without having to install a separate `clang-format` binary through Homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed `clang-format` via `brew`, the `clang-format` has been downloaded under

(Just use my MacOS12.3.1+XCode13.4+clang-format@5.0 with upgrade from macOS10.12.6+Xcode8+clang-format@5.0 as an example)

```
/usr/local/Cellar/clang-format@5/
```

with it's executable file `clang-format` under

```
/usr/local/Cellar/clang-format@5/5.0.2/bin/clang-format
```

with it's configuration file `clang-format.py` under

```
/usr/local/Cellar/clang-format@5/5.0.2/share/clang/clang-format.py
```

ALso,

the clang-format@5.0 will create soft link executable file `clang-format` under

```
/usr/local/bin/clang-format -> ../Cellar/clang-format@5/5.0.2/bin/clang-format
```

(that's why while I check where the clang-format is no matter using `where clang-format` or `which clang-format` or even `whereis clang-format`, that always shows `/usr/local/bin/clang-format`.)

(If you want to check where soft link `/usr/local/bin/clang-format` linked to?
Just use the command to check `cd /usr/local/bin/ && pwd && ls -al | grep "clang-format"`, liking mine showing:)

```
/usr/local/bin/clang-format -> ../Cellar/clang-format@5/5.0.2/bin/clang-format
```

and the clang-format@5.0  soft link create configuration file `clang-format.py` under

```
/usr/local/share/clang/clang-format.py
```

the upstairs soft link linked to

```
/usr/local/Cellar/clang-format@5/5.0.2/share/clang/clang-format.py
```

Others,

somebody's download clang-format@3.8 maybe under

```
/usr/local/Cellar/clang-format
```

with executable file `clang-format`under

```
/usr/local/Cellar/clang-format/2019-01-18/bin/clang-format
```

with configuration file `clang-format.py` under

```
/usr/local/Cellar/clang-format/2019-01-18/share/clang/clang-format.py
```

withe the upstairs soft link `clang-format.py` under

```
/usr/share/clang/clang-format-3.8/clang-format.py
```