# How to applying clang-format to all project files at once in Xcode for Objective C?

Tags: xcode, clang, clang-format

I have installed clang-format by cloning https://github.com/travisjeffery/ClangFormat-Xcode.git.

This works fine for applying clang-format for selected files. But I wanted to know if there is some other approach (any command line option) to apply for all files at once.

Comment: If you want a GUI, you could try [Xformat](https://mattrajca.com/xformat).

Answer (score 0):

**To use the command line**

You need to download clang-format for MacOS and use that tool from within Terminal.app.

**How to get the binaries and setup**

The following stackoverflow answer discusses using *Homebrew* to get the MacOS binaries: [Where are clang-format and clang-format.py in Mac OS X with Xcode Command Line Tools installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21151731/where-are-clang-format-and-clang-format-py-in-mac-os-x-with-xcode-command-line-t)

I followed the instructions on https://nacho4d-nacho4d.blogspot.de/2013/11/clang-format.html to:

1. Download clang binaries for MacOS
2. Move un-tarred files to ~/Development/Tools/clang+llvm-3.9.0-x86_64-apple-darwin folder
3. Create an alias in .bash_login named cformat

I prefer downloading files over using Homebrew, but you can choose whatever method you want.

If you choose to download the clang binaries yourself, you may want to use a bash alias over adding the clang binaries path to the PATH variable, in case of a binary name collision.

To add the bash alias, open .bash_login in your favorite text editor and add the following line:
`alias cformat=~/Development/Tools/clang+llvm-3.9.0-x86_64-apple-darwin/bin/clang-format`

You would change the path to wherever you place the clang binaries.

**To format all files within a project folder**

From within Terminal.app, cd to the source directory you want to format and type `cformat *.m` ; you can use whatever wildcard you want; clang-format will output the changes it will make to the window. If you are satisfied with the results and want clang-format to change the files for you, type `cformat -i *.m` and all of the Objective-C files within that folder will be formatted for you.

**Settings for clang-format**

The clang-format tool will look for a file named .clang-format in the immediate directory you are in and walk up to see if it can find one to know what settings it should use.

You can experiment with different settings by placing your preferences in a .clang-format file (I placed mine in my home directory) and you can look at the different clang-format styles by typing `cformat -style=llvm -dump-config > ~/.clang-format` in Terminal.app.

The styles that come with clang-format include "LLVM, Google, Chromium, Mozilla, WebKit".